# jQuery losing click handler after loading div

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is situation: Im making content changing of my page with **.load('page.php')** function. But my problem is following. When i change content like this , my **.click()** functions dont work anymore.

Here is my .js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".menu_inner").bind('click',function(){
    var product = $(this).attr('prod');
    produkt="modules/"+product+".php";  
  })

  $(".menu_list_home").click(function(){
    $("#contentwrapper").load('modules/homepage.php');
  })

})
```

It is ok with homepage bind cause div where it is refreshed is not where homebutton is. It is working when page loads. As soon as i click on home, there is nothing to do. It looks like it was unbinded. Any guess?

Martin.

Comment: whats the html layout like, is the menu_inner within the contentwrapper etc

Comment: Does '(".menu_list_home")' contains '(".menu_inner")' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I belive that dom having class `menu_inner` is also getting changed when you load 'contentwrapper'. Use this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.menu_inner', function(){
ar product = $(this).attr('prod');
produkt="modules/"+product+".php"; 
} );
```